# algorithm for connectivity by path of given length

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

Given an unweighted, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ without loops or multiedges, and vertices $v,w$, one can use breadth-first search to check if $v$, $w$ are connected, and in particular the algorithm will return a shortest path between them.
BFS has time complexity $O(|V|+|E|)=O(|V|^2)$.

Now let $k$ be some fixed integer (not part of the input).
Is there an algorithm that takes $G$, $v,$ $w$, and checks whether there is a path between $v$ and $w$ of length $k$? What would be its time complexity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is NP-complete and referred to as [Longest Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem).  It is FPT, though, so you can solve it in time polynomial in $n$ for *fixed* $k$.

If you want to solve it in FPT time, the easiest solution is to do *color coding*.  The trick is two-fold.

1. Suppose that vertices are colored with $k$ colors, and you are looking for a rainbow-path of length $k$, i.e. a path where every vertex has different color.  This problem can be solved by dynamic programming!
2. Repeat the following step: Randomly color the vertices of the graph with $k$ colors, and run the rainbow algorithm.

With probability depending only on $k$, *if* there exists a $k$-path, then you will output a rainbow path.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the case when $k$ is fixed? This is the case I am interested in, and I've edited my question to reflect this. The article mentions something about 'dynamic programming' for this case. Is there a simpler approach to getting polynomial in $n$ for fixed $k$?

Comment: @MerkZockerborg There's a rich literature for the problem. One method you can search for is *color coding*.

Comment: @MerkZockerborg, how many paths of length $k$ are there?  If you were to enumerate all of them, how long would that take?

Answer (score 2):

If the required path doesn't need to be **simple**, then there's a dynamic programming solution. Assume that the given graph is specified by an adjacency matrix $G$. Let $F_k(v, w)$ be the answer for input $k$, $v$ and $w$. So we have a formula:

$$ F_k(v, w) = \bigvee_u F_{k - 1}(v, u) \wedge G(u, w) $$

This kind of formula can be calculated using matrix multiplication: we use the **AND** operator instead of multiplication, and take the **OR** of them instead of the sum. Time complexity is $O(|V|^3 \log k)$.